# python symbol calculation: substitute old expression by new expression or symbol

Tags: python, symbols, calculation, simplify

I am learning python to calculate partial derivative. I have function

```
y = x1**2 + 2*x1
```

with

```
x1 = 2 *x + 1
```

and want to get value of `diff(y, x)`.

Coding as follows;

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np  

x = sp.symbols('x')
x1 = 2*x + 1

y = x1**2 + 2 * x1

ans = sp.diff(y, x)
```

I got

```
ans = 8*x + 8
```

I want to use `"x1"` in replace of `"x"` in the final result
i.e. `"4 * x1 + 4"`

How do I do that?

Comment: Then why not use `'x = sp.symbols('x1')'`